# explaining $\lambda$-calculus/functional programming to someone used to Turing machines/procedural programming?

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming

**I have the following background:**

- I have experience with object-oriented programming languages
- I find Turing machines and the concept of a "procedure" very intuitive.

Yet I'm interested to understand the idea behind the abstract $\lambda$-calculus, and its application in the form of functional programming.

**When I read about either $\lambda$-calculus or functional programming, these explanations tend to either:**

1. make reference to practical benefits that seem generally beneficial to me, but don't give me a fundamental-principled understanding. E.g. that functional programming languages are more modular and less error-prone because there are no state-dependencies.
2. or assume an already existing intuitive familiarity with either $\lambda$-calculus or the practicalities of functional programming. (Essentially these explanations suffer from the curse of knowledge: the authors cannot place themselves in the shoes of someone who doesn't have their intuition yet).

**So I am looking for a general, principled, theoretical understanding of the conceptual and formal difference between (1) $\lambda$-calculus and Turing machines, and between (2) functional programming and procedural programming.**

Comment: In case 2, you just may not be in the target audience of those articles. At any rate "functional programming" and "procedural programming" do not have any widely accepted formal definitions. The lambda calculus and Turing machines are just very different, so the similarities are more surprising than the differences.

Comment: At any rate, I usually recommend that programmers interested in the lambda calculus *do* get practical familiarity with a language like Haskell or Scheme. This is usually much less abstract and more rewarding than trying to deal with dry formalism. Once you do have that background, the formalism becomes more relevant, less dry, and can be viewed as a kind of minimal or core "functional language". If you tried to explain to a non-programmer that Turing machines can compute anything a computer can, you'd likely get a question like "how do you play video with a Turing machine?"

Comment: I second Derek Elkins's suggestion. Learning the $\lambda$-calculus before having functional programming experience is a bit like learning TMs before having experience in imperative programming. If you are doing that only for theoretical purposes, that is doable, but your point 1) above shows you want to see more practice. Take a FP language tutorial (Haskell,Scheme,Ocaml,...) and follow it. It's perfectly possible to learn FP by-doing, seeing examples. You can even see some FP in action in Javascript,Scala,Java,... with proper libraries. (I'd still recommend using a fully FP language after)

Comment: @chi, no I don't want to see practice. I am purely interested in the theory. I am not interested in this for programming's sake, but for theoretical computer science/foundations of mathematics sake. I'd want to understand functional programming in principle, but don't need to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to second both Derek Elkins' and Chi's comments. You can do Functional Programming in most languages, but it requires the discipline to adhere to the functional principles. It's probably harder to learn FP in a language like Javascript\Python because you'll have to fight against the urge to do things the old way you already know.

In a Functional Programming Language (i.e. purely functional) you'll have to do stuff THE FUNCTIONAL WAY, without taking corners. Also, doing practical stuff means you'll have to learn some theory as well.

---

> 1. make reference to practical benefits that seem generally beneficial to me, but don't give me a fundamental-principled understanding. E.g. that functional programming languages are more modular and less error-prone because there are no state-dependencies.

Something I really like about functional languages (and is kinda contained in what you said about error-proneness) is they often have some pretty amazing Type Systems.

Let's look at a "Hello World" in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The function `main` takes no arguments and returns an `Int`, but there's no way I would know that it is actually doing IO inside it's body, unless I look at the functions body.

I can even change it and only get a warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* main(){
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}

hello.c:3:7: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
 char* main(){
```

The same code in Haskell,

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "hello world"
```

The function `putStrLn` has type `Str -> IO()`, to put it simply, it takes a String and returns some `IO()` stuff. Main also returns `IO()`.

If I try to change the main's type to `main :: String` I would get the following error:

```
module Main where

main :: String
main = do
  putStrLn "hello world"


hello/src/Main.hs:4:1: error:

    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘IO t0’
      Expected type: IO t0
        Actual type: String
    • In the expression: main
      When checking the type of the IO action ‘main’
  |
4 | main = do
  | ^

hello/src/Main.hs:5:3: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO ()’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: IO ()
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn "hello world"
      In the expression: do putStrLn "hello world"
      In an equation for ‘main’: main = do putStrLn "hello world"
  |
5 |   putStrLn "hello world"
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is, Haskell is telling me that `putStrLn` will return some `IO()`, so `main` is expected to do the same, since it returns `putStrLn`. Actually it wasn't even required to give `main` a type, since Haskell has a pretty powerful Type System based on [Hindley–Milner Type Inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system).

This was a really trivial example, but it is often the case that most Runtime Errors in many languages will be caught as Compilation Errors in pure functional languages. Some languages, like [Coq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq), are so strong that you can prove theorems with it!

> 2. or assume an already existing intuitive familiarity with either $\lambda$-calculus or the practicalities of functional programming. (Essentially these explanations suffer from the curse of knowledge: the authors cannot place themselves in the shoes of someone who doesn't have their intuition yet).

This is actually a problem with Haskell [(Survey 2017)](http://taylor.fausak.me/2017/11/15/2017-state-of-haskell-survey-results/)

> Most people want the Haskell community to be bigger. To that end, many
>   people want the community to be less divisive (for example Stack
>   versus Cabal) or less elitist (for example putting down other
>   languages). Also more beginner and intermediate documentation and
>   tutorials would help.

---

Some pure Functional languages you might want to give a try:

- Haskell
- Elm
- Coq

Here are some references I've been using through the years to get some familiarity with FP and it's theory.

Some references on the $\lambda$-Calculus:

**Books**

- [Lambda-Calculus and Combinators](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/computer-science/programming-languages-and-applied-logic/lambda-calculus-and-combinators-introduction-2nd-edition?format=HB&isbn=9780521898850): I've only read the first 3 chapters, but it's a pretty solid introduction to the theory of $\lambda$-calculus.

**Lecture Notes**

- [Lambda-Calculus and Types](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/andrew.ker/docs/lambdacalculus-lecture-notes-ht2009.pdf): Lecture notes from a Oxford class with the same name.
- [Lecture Notes on the Lambda Calculus](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.3434.pdf): Lecture notes from the University of Ottawa.
- [Introduction to Functional Programming](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/Lectures/funprog-jrh-1996/all.pdf): Lecture notes from a Cambridge course.

**Quick Talks**

- [Adam McCullough - Greek Classics: Lambda Calculus For Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DPlj75YJR4)
- [Steven Syrek - Lambda Calculus For People Who Can't Be Bothered to Learn It - part 1 of 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_ReqkiyCXo)
- [Steven Syrek - Lambda Calculus For People Who Can't Be Bothered to Learn It - part 2 of 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lM825quliY)

**Lectures**

- [Dana Scott - Theory and Models of Lambda Calculus Untyped and Typed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBjhDyHFqJY) : A five lecture series by Dana Scott.

Some theory about Functional Programming:

**Books**

- The Algebra of Programming
- Purely Functional Data Structures
- [Type Theory and Functional Programming](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/TTFP/)
- [Software Foundations](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/TTFP/): A free course on Coq, Functional Programming, Logic and Program Correctness.

Implementation of Functional Programming Languages

- Design Concepts in Programming Languages
- [Implementing functional languages: a tutorial](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/implementing-functional-languages-a-tutorial/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fum%2Fpeople%2Fsimonpj%2Fpapers%2Fpj-lester-book%2F)

**Lecture Notes**

- [Foundations of Functional Programming](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Notes/Founds-FP.pdf)